# How can I have a global extendable object holding instances with type information in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I am porting a JavaScript application to TypeScript and the app makes use of a global container variable for common functions and variables. This variable, let's call it `Engine`, is in the global scope and contains stuff like assert or log functions, to avoid that you have to import those for every single file.

Also, `Engine` contains important instances, like a NetworkManager, which are used from everywhere. Those instances get added to `Engine` dynamically during the application initialization by different classes.

I am less concerned about the scoping issues of having a global variable, but more of the approach in general and how to modify this object from different modules without having a full type declaration in one spot.

What is the best practice for TypeScript here?